# Can't find environment variable in ancestors SwiftUI error

Tags: view, environment-variables, components, swiftui

Here's my UserProfile Component

```
struct UserProfile: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

    ...
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("uid: \(session.session?.uid ?? "")")
            Text("email: \(session.session?.email ?? "")")
            Button(action: signOut, label: {
                Text("Log out")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And the parent of the userProfile view has this in it

```
NavigationLink(destination: UserProfile()){
                            Image(systemName: "person.circle").resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25.0, height: 25.0)
                        }
```

And for some reason when I get to the userProfile component I get the error

```
No ObservableObject of type SessionStore found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for SessionStore may be missing as an ancestor of this view.
```

The session is definitely available in the parent view view because this works

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("\(session.session!.uid)")){
                            Image(systemName: "person.circle").resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25.0, height: 25.0)
                        }
```

and for some reason this works too

```
NavigationLink(destination: UserProfile().environmentObject(session)){
                            Image(systemName: "person.circle").resizable()
                            .frame(width: 25.0, height: 25.0)
                        }
```

Any explanations?

Comment: Where this instruction `NavigationLink(destination: UserProfile())` is located in code? Which Xcode Version do you use?

Comment: NavigationLink(destination: UserProfile()) is in the parent view which is wrapped in a NavigationView(). This is Xcode 11.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know the answer. It's that the destination of a NavigationLink isn't considered a child of the parent view and thus won't inherit its environment. Thus the only way to solve this is to send in, again, the environmentObject that you want to pass down.